# Getting null value on declaring String as a Control in Windows Form using Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

I tried this code to declare some string which would act as a given Control in my application form.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Test12 As Control = Controls("Button1")
    Test12.Text = "Working"
End Sub
```

But, I am getting the value for Test12 is *'NULL'* as shown below. I have confirmed my form contains Control name as **Button1**

[image]

Comment: You may look at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3N68pbxw_ho

Comment: A control is an object, a string is just a string. the title makes no sense. And it seems very odd that you would have a Textbox named "Button1".  A control is not the same as a TextBox - you should turn on Option Strict

Comment: Are you sure that your control is contained in the form control collection and not in another container (groupbox, panel....)?

Comment: I didn't said I have have a Textbox named "Button1". It is a button and of course we can change the text for a button.

Comment: @Steve !!!!!!!!! you got it... I was actually thinking that way but wasn't able to ask it though... and yeah it is in a panel...

Comment: So it is in the panel's control collection

Comment: @Steve Any solution for this? :(

Comment: Fish it out of the controls collection it is in,  but Control and button are also different types

Comment: Use the Panel _Dim Test12 As Control = myPanel.Controls("Button1")_

Comment: Thanks!. Worked @Steve

Comment: Wondering why he didn't just do Button1.Text = whatever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve was right.
Just add this word to your line of code, example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim Test12 As Control = PanelName.Controls("Button1") 'Edited Line
Test12.Text = "Working"
End Sub
```

Where **PanelName** is the name of your Panel that contains your control "Button1"